# Backbone Router doesn't appear to correctly Extending Router

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, require, router

```
define([
 'jquery',
 'underscore',
 'backbone',
  'app',
  'models/sessionmodel',
  'views/home/homeview',

], function(
    $,
    _,
    Backbone,
    app,
    SessionModel,
    HomeView
){
  AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

     initialize: function(options){},

     routes : {
       ''            :'showhome',
     },

    showhome : function(){
      this.show(new HomeView());
    },


    });

    return AppRouter;

});
```

And here is my Main That is first hit per Backbone standards. I have another file called app that created an empty object and returns it...

```
require.config({
paths: {
jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.2',
underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-1.0.0-min',
text: 'libs/require/text',
router: 'router',
app: 'app'
},
shim: {
    jquery: {
        exports: '$'
    },
    underscore: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
        deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
        exports: "Backbone"
    }
}
});

require(['app','router', 'models/sessionmodel'], function(app, AppRouter, SessionModel) {

    app.router = new AppRouter();
    app.session = new SessionModel();
    app.session.checkAuth({

        complete: function(){
            Backbone.history.start();
        }
    });
});
```

When I console log this, the router is missing its default methods (specifically navigate, but in addition others like on, off, trigger, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you don't check the `__proto__` property of the logged object:[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate it:  `var router = new AppRouter();`

Comment: I added in my main file where I instantiate the approuter. Sorry about that, thanks.